# Hibernate basic configuration in Spring 3 project - Class not found exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to set up `Hibernate 3.6` in my existing `Spring 3 MVC` + `Spring 3 security` project. Nevertheless I keep getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` in my `HibernateUtil` class - line with `return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

`hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3049/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="./DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`DBUser.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="../src/main/java/user/DBUser" table="DBUSER">
        <id name="userId" type="int">
            <column name="USER_ID" precision="5" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="USERNAME" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdBy" type="string">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="date">
            <column name="CREATED_DATE" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And a relevant part of the `pom.xml` file:

```
<!-- Hibernate + MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

EDIT: I've pasted [here the stack trace](http://pastebin.com/yG4Zi6Sp). It was too long to put it right here, because it would make this post confused.

I'd be really glad, if someone could help me with setting up this thing, because I've got no idea, why it can't find that class.

Comment: a stack trace would help.

Comment: I think you have more dependencies to add in your POM: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.3.Final (This artifact depends on ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the javaassist library. Download the [javaassist](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/Javassist/3.12.0.GA/javassist-3.12.GA.zip/download) jar and add it to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Your class name should be the package path to the Hibernate POJO in DBUser.hbm.xml, e.g:

```
user/DBUser
```

And your mapping resource does not need `./` in the path.